# fish shell functions not accessing user paths

Tags: fish

I've recently started using fish, and I needed to use a `jar` file for google's bundletool.

As such, I needed to set up an alias/function for bundletool, and I chose a function since it seems more "fishy".

My function is simple:

```
function bundletool
    java -jar bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar $argv
end
```

The bundletool jar itself lives at `~/.local/bin`, which is on my fish user path:

```
lase@laser-razer /m/c/U/matth [1]> echo $fish_user_paths
/home/lase/.local/bin /usr/local/go/bin /home/lase/.nvm /home/lase/.cargo/bin /home/lase/.cargo
```

In a regular shell, I can execute `java -jar bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar`, and the command runs as expected. However, in the function, fish doesn't seem to know about my `fish_user_paths`, and reports it cannot find the `jar` file.

To remedy this, I had to update my function to specify the full path:

```
function bundletool
    java -jar ~/.local/bin/bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar $argv
end
```

This works, but I feel like I'm doing something incorrectly. Should I be setting up my paths or functions in a different fashion?

Comment: By "in a _regular_ shell", do you mean an interactive _fish_ shell? What is your current directory in your in the "regular shell"? Is it ~/.local/bin? From what I can see at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html referencing the jar file without a path means it must be in the current directory, otherwise the path must be given.

Comment: Perhaps you want `function bundletool; cd ~/.local/bin; java -jar bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar $argv; end`

Comment: That `cd` will cause the entire shell to switch directories, it'll leave you in that directory. If you needed the working directory change you could `pushd` and `popd`, but here it should be simpler to just use the full path to the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function will run in the ordinary environment.

It will run with the current $PATH [0] and, more importantly to you, the current working directory.

What happens is this:

```
java -jar bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar
```

Will tell `java` to run the jar found at `bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar`.

Notably, fish just hands java the string "bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar", and java will then not look at $PATH. It does not care about $PATH. It simply looks at "bundletool-all-1.12.1.jar", and tries to open a file by that name.

And it will find that file, if it is in the current directory.

And that's the reason this worked for you when you executed it interactively - because you happened to be in that directory

And then you tried it with the function, but you tried it from a different directory, and so it didn't work.

> This works, but I feel like I'm doing something incorrectly. Should I be setting up my paths or functions in a different fashion?

No, giving the full path to the file instead of relying on the working directory is the right thing to do.

---

[0]: $fish_user_paths is just a variable you set, that fish will then take care to add to $PATH. $PATH is the actual variable that fish and other tools (including any command fish starts, if it wants to) will use to find commands.

Comment: Thanks faho! That is important and helpful context. It makes much more sense now.